# How to use window.open inside the window.load function event

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, dom-events

Should I use `window.open()` inside `window.onload` function in Javascript? If not how to use that in `window.onload="url"`. Please show me some example. Here below is what am trying to do. The text validation is working fine. Once I enter run string its not going to open the `evovle.jsp (concern url)

e.g.:

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 function validatetxtbox() 
{      var txtfield;    
     txtfield =document.getElementById('txtbox').value; 
       if(txtfield == "run") 
     {  alert("you entered string right"); 
       
 window.onload=function(){window.open('evolve.jsp''welcome' 'width=500,height=500,menubar=yes,status=yes,location=yes,toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes');}           
 } 
else  {  alert("Try again");  }  
}      
</script>
 </head>

<body> 
<input type="text" id="txtbox" maxlength="3">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Send" onclick="validatetxtbox()"> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script ="text/javascript">
  function check() {
 var txtfield; txtfield =document.getElementById('txtbox').value; 
 if(txtfield == "run")
 { alert("you entered string right");
 var newwin=window.open('evolve.jsp','welcome','width=500,height=500,menubar=yes,status=yes,location=yes,toolbar=yes');
 newwin.focus();
 } 
 else { alert("Try again"); } 
  }
 </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  Enter a Keayword
  <input type="text" id="txtbox" onblur="check()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for ur prompty reply ...madhav!! instead of onblur cant i use onclick...for the button.

Comment: @hari if you hve a button you can call the same method with onclick Event it will make equal sense

Answer (score 0):

Use querystring and check in evolve.jsp 
**Ex** evolve.jsp#alertme